# Creating a timed metadata track in MP4

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mp4, mp4parser, mp4box

The BMFF defines a meta data track as a track which can appear in the media file in addition to video & audio tracks.
Such a track can be in the form of xml (metx), text (mett) or binary (urim).

Is there a library which is capable of taking a mp4 file as an input and appending a metadata track to it?
Is there a sample mp4 to inspect and learn the exact structure of such a file?

Specifically, I'm interested in adding such a track to a fragmented mp4 file.

Comment: any progress on this?

Comment: Did anyone figure this out ?